# emacs --eval of multiple functions on command line

Tags: command-line-arguments, eval-expression, eval

How do I evaluate multiple functions simultaneously using emacs --eval on command line? For example I want to combine the followings in a single command:

```
emacs --eval "(toggle-frame-maximized)"
emacs --eval "(sr-speedbar-toggle)"
```

I tried to wrap them together but all attempts failed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use `(progn )`. This should address your question:

```
emacs --eval "(progn (toggle-frame-maximized) (sr-speedbar-toggle))"
```

Please note that this does not execute the commands simultaneously (as you requested). It executes one command after another.

Comment: Or `emacs -f toggle-frame-maximized -f sr-speedbar-toggle`, and maybe multiple `--eval` works as well?

Comment: What should we do for the multiple commands?